# How to create a IDirect3DSurface from an IBuffer or byte array in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, com, media

I want to create a video from a few `RenderTargetBitmap`s in UWP. I am doing that by using `MediaClips`.
From `RenderTargetBitmap` i can get an `IBuffer` or byte array of pixels.
To create a `MediaClip` I need either an image file or an `IDirect3DSurface`.
Creating an image just to create a clip is very expensive, so I thought of using `IDirect3DSurface`. 
How can I do this?
I have tried this:

```
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(RenderedGrid, 100, 100);

        IBuffer pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
        var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DirectXPixelFormat));
        CanvasBitmap bitmap=null;

        foreach (DirectXPixelFormat format in values)
        {
            try
            {
                videoClip = new MediaComposition();
                bitmap = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(myWidget.Device, pixels, renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, format);
                StorageFile video2 = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("video2" + ".mp4", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                MediaClip d = MediaClip.CreateFromSurface(bitmap, DateTime.Now - previousFrame+new TimeSpan(100));
                videoClip.Clips.Add(d);
                await videoClip.RenderToFileAsync(video2);
                break;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

I try all the formats in `DirectXPixelFormat` but none works.

I have a `CanvasControl` named `myWidget` that is empty.

I create a `CanvasBitmap` from `Ibuffer` (`CanvasBitmap` implements `IDirect3DSurface`)

Create a `Mediaclip` from `CanvasBitmap`

`Add it to MediaComposition`.

Then I try to render to video file.When i try to save to a file it throws an error

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Stream is not in a state
>   to handle the request.

EDIT:
I figured out where the problem is, but not why and not how to fix it.

```
            await videoClip.SaveAsync(video2);
            videoClip= await MediaComposition.LoadAsync(video2);
            var x=await videoClip.RenderToFileAsync(video2);
```

Now with these three lines i can save the video, but using only the third line it throws the error above. I cannot make sense of it. Why does saving and loading fix the problem??

Answer (score 1):

Most probable reason is that, `CanvasBitmap` has an underlying `IDirce3DSurface` object as well as image data like `byte[]` or something else , though I am not sure about this.

If that's true, then creating a `CanvasBitmap` from `byte[]` or `IBuffer` won't effect the underlying `IDirect3DSurface`, the image part will be constructed only. You can see that by saving that image on the disk, it gives no error.

But **I think there's a workaround if you want to skip saving data on the disk**:

You can contruct the underlying `IDirect3DSurface` if you do [Offscreen Drawing](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Offscreen.htm) to a [CanvasRenderTarget](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_CanvasRenderTarget.htm).

So, you can use the `CanvasBitmap` to construct a `CanvasRenderTarget` and then use that `CanvasRenderTarget` to contruct a `MediaClip`:

```
CanvasRenderTarget rendertarget;
using (CanvasBitmap canvas = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), pixels, renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth, renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight, format))
{
     rendertarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), canvas.SizeInPixels.Width, canvas.SizeInPixels.Height, 96);
     using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = rendertarget.CreateDrawingSession())
     {
         ds.Clear(Colors.Black);
         ds.DrawImage(canvas);
     }
}
MediaClip d = MediaClip.CreateFromSurface(renderTarget, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(80));
mc.Clips.Add(m);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MediaComposition.RenderToFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.editing.mediacomposition.rendertofileasync#Windows_Media_Editing_MediaComposition_RenderToFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_) Method saves the composition to a video file that can be played back with standard media players. From the error info, it seems the stream content is not correct media data and can not be render into a video file directly.

So, to create a video from a few RenderTargetBitmaps in UWP, the way to use an image file should be your choice. using [MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.editing.mediaclip.createfromimagefileasync#Windows_Media_Editing_MediaClip_CreateFromImageFileAsync_Windows_Storage_IStorageFile_Windows_Foundation_TimeSpan_) method by saving the [RenderTargetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap) into a file then using it to create a video.

```
private async void CreateVideoByConvertRenderBitmapToFile()
{
    var folder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("Test", 
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var composition = new MediaComposition();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap render = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await render.RenderAsync(RenderGrid);
        MyImage.Source = render;
        var pixel = await render.GetPixelsAsync();
        var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync("test.png", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
        {
            var logicalDpi = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi;
            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(
                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                (uint)render.PixelWidth,
                (uint)render.PixelHeight,
                logicalDpi,
                logicalDpi,
                pixel.ToArray());
            await encoder.FlushAsync();
            stream.Dispose();
            MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(file, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            composition.Clips.Add(clip);
            MyText.Text = "First frame >>>" + i;
        }
    }
    var video = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("test.mp4",
        CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    var action = await composition.RenderToFileAsync(video, MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise);
    await folder.DeleteAsync();
}
```

Comment: I dont want to use the second solution because I am using hololens and it is very expensive to write and read to file for each screenshot (i am creating a video). 
Please see my edited question

Comment: Have you seen my edited post? Can you suggest a solution or a workaround? What could it be that saving and loading fixes the problem?

Comment: I'm with you. Writing a png file to disk for each frame doesn't look optimal

Comment: Another problem: "Content that's in the XAML visual tree but offscreen can be captured, so long as it's not Visibility = Collapsed or in the other restricted cases."
This is big inconvenient, because it doesn't let you render something that is not connected to the visual tree. If you want to create a video, you don't want to render everything on-screen, but as a "hidden" processing against a disconnected `Control`. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.RenderTargetBitmap#xaml-visuals-and-rendertargetbitmap-capture-capabilities