# Create video from UI controls in UWP using Composition

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I'm creating an application that takes a video and overlays sensor data from a drone.

Please, watch it in action here:

https://youtu.be/eAOjImJci3M

But that doesn't edit the video, it's just on the application.

My goal is to produce a new video with the overlaid data on it. How can I capture an element of the UI over time and make a `MediaClip` out of it?

Comment: This is kind of is along the same vein as what you're describing. Capture the application and saving it to video. In your case, you want the video and the overlay. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51027900/how-to-create-a-idirect3dsurface-from-an-ibuffer-or-byte-array-in-uwp

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but the question is still unacceptable, since it needs to generate a file (on disk) for each frame.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the answer, not the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: Take a screenshot of the UI with a certain interval, and then accumulate them to produce a video:

**Long answer**: Let's name the UI you want to record as `myGrid`, to get screenshots in an interval you can use a `DispatcerTimer`, and handle the `Tick` event like this:

```
private async void Tm_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap rendertargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await rendertargetBitmap.RenderAsync(myGrid);
    var bfr = await rendertargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

    CanvasRenderTarget rendertarget = null
    using (CanvasBitmap canvas = CanvasBitmap.CreateFromBytes(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), bfr, rendertargetBitmap.PixelWidth, rendertargetBitmap.PixelHeight, Windows.Graphics.DirectX.DirectXPixelFormat.B8G8R8A8UIntNormalized))
    {
        rendertarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice(), canvas.SizeInPixels.Width, canvas.SizeInPixels.Height, 96);
        using (CanvasDrawingSession ds = rendertarget.CreateDrawingSession())
        {
            ds.Clear(Colors.Black);
            ds.DrawImage(canvas);
        }
    }
    MediaClip m = MediaClip.CreateFromSurface(rendertarget, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(80));
    mc.Clips.Add(m);
}
```

`mc` is the `MediaComposition` object I declared earlier .

When you are done recording, stop the `DispatcherTimer` and save the video on the disk like this:

```
tm.Stop();
await mc.RenderToFileAsync(file, MediaTrimmingPreference.Precise, MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Vga));
```

`tm` is the `DispatcherTimer` I declared earlier and `file` is a `StorageFile` with mp4 extension.

**This procedure doesn't require you to save each screenshot to disk .**

If you wonder why I used an additional `CanvasRenderTarget`, it's because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52817768/4648930) problem.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll try that ASAP! Thank you. By the way, could you please take a look to this other question about overlays? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815829/how-to-create-video-with-overlays-in-uwp Thanks again, in advance :)

Comment: there was a problem with the previous example. try this now.

Comment: I'm already using your code and it works! BUt I have a big problem with the memory this consumes: I'm generating a video out of more than 5000 still images and it always makes my PC run out of memory. With only 300 images, it takes up to 6 GB of RAM.

Comment: Well, that's normal I think. The trade off between memory and speed. You can save each bitmap on the local drive , then it won't  take that much RAM. but it will be slow then. One thing is that, I have always seen video rendering making pc slow.

Comment: I checked it in my pc, which has a total of 4 GB RAM. Yes , the RAM consumption is too much. What's interesting is that, in my pc, after it surpasses 1.5 GB of RAM, it goes backwards to 150 MB RAM very quickly.  I think the GC starts working then. So, you can try explicitely calling the GC to start it's duty.

Comment: Also, after finishing rendering, clear the`clip` list : `mc.Clips.Clear()`